# How to remove duplicate buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created five buttons using for loop, it works well. Whenever i click restart button duplicate buttons created

```
-(void)buttonCreate {
  for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
  {
    oneBtn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    oneBtn1.frame = CGRectMake(316,i*-5+474,51,50);
    [oneBtn1 setTag:i];
    [oneBtn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(oneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [oneBtn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1c.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:oneBtn1];
  }
}
```

Restart button function:

```
-(void)restart {
    [self buttonCreate];
}
```

I tried this one but it will remove only one button out of 5.

```
if(oneBtn1 != NULL) {
    [oneBtn1 removeFromSuperview];
    oneBtn1 = nil;
}
```

Problem is: How to remove duplicate buttons?

Comment: what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove by checking if the button is already created.

```
-(void)buttonCreate {
  int tag_start = 500;
  for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
  {
    UIView * prevbtn = [self.view viewWithTag:tag_start + i];
    if(prevbtn) {
         [prevbtn removeFromSuperview];
    }

    oneBtn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    oneBtn1.frame = CGRectMake(316,i*-5+474,51,50);
    [oneBtn1 setTag:tag_start + i];
    [oneBtn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(oneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [oneBtn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1c.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:oneBtn1];
  }
}
```

Comment: but what is that tag_start mean? if i remove that one my uiview display black screen

Comment: tag_start is just to add some unique tag for last button. if not added, first button will have tag as 0. which is default value. In case you want to do any tag related operations, you need to assign unique tags to your view

Comment: i tried to create another five button (fiveBtn1) using the same procedure. it also works but oneBtn1 was removed.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array(`NSMutableArray *buttonHolderArray`) to hold outlets for all five buttons.

```
[buttonHolderArray addObject:oneBtn1];
```

Then you can remove/update the buttons as and when you need.

And once you dont want any button, empty the array itself. On top of this, if you wish to clear the view then simply call  `removeFromSuperView` for all the buttons

```
I tried this one but it will remove only one button out of 5.

if(oneBtn1 != NULL) {
    [oneBtn1 removeFromSuperview];
    oneBtn1 = nil;
}
```

You are removing only one button, if you want to remove all then use

```
for ( UIButton *button in buttonHolderArray){
      button removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Comment: how to create a five button using array in buttonCreate() function which i specified above

Comment: ur for loop is sufficient enough to create five buttons.

Comment: how can i display buttons from an array to viewcontroller.  Because i display whole buttons with a single name.

Answer (score 0):

use this before calling again  **restart** method

```
for (UIButton *btn in self.view.subviews ) {

        [btn removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the restart button clicked you can remove all the buttons from you view calling the method `removeChildViewsWithKindOfClass`

```
-(void)restart {
    [self.view removeChildViewsWithKindOfClass:[UIButton class]];
    [self buttonCreate];
}

-(void)removeChildViewsWithKindOfClass:(Class)classToRemove{
    if (classToRemove==nil) return;

    for (UIView *v in [self subviews]) {
        if ([v isKindOfClass:classToRemove]) {
            [v removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to remove a specific button you can use the property `tag` that you have to set beforehand when you create your button and it allows you removing the button with a specific tag.

Comment: how to add button instead of UIView

Comment: what do you mean? You add buttons using your code. The method I published is for removing them from superview.